# Angular router not opening child pages

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, angular-router

I have this in my app-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

In my home-routing.module I have the following:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create-bet',
    component: CreateBetComponent,
    children: [{ path: 'bet-duration-select', component: BetDurationSelectComponent }],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: '*', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

When I am on the home component ('[...]/home') I have a button that I want to use to navigate to '/create-bet'. I was expecting doing something like this would work:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/create-bet');
```

But this just redirects me back to '/home'. However if I change the path to

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/create-bet');
```

I am correctly redirected to that URL and the component is shown. Why is it that I have to specify 'home' in the path?

Furthermore, on the create-bet Page, I have a button that I want to use to navigate to its child page ('bet-duration-select') like so:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/bet-duration-select');
```

Again, I was expecting this to work however, it redirects me back to the '/home' URL.
Even if I specify the route as

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/create-bet/bet-duration-select');
```

or

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/create-bet/bet-duration-select');
```

I am always redirected back to '/home'.

Can someone explain to me why that behavior is happenning? I thought the way I had it set up should work...
Even if I type out the url in the nav bar directly'[...]/home/create-bet/bet-duration-select' the 'create-bet' component is shown, instead of the bet-duration-select. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your case you have

```
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

path '**' means 'any URL', so when Angular can't find specified URL, it redirects you to '/home'. Usualy this route is using for 404 page.

2. You have to write full path to component from root like this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/create-bet/bet-duration-select');
```

because `BetDurationSelectComponent` is a child component of `CreateBetComponent` and grandchild of `HomeComponent`. The routes in Angular app looks like a tree, so you have something like this:

```
/    <-- root
∟ home
 ∟ create-bet
  ∟ bet-duration-select
∟ login
```

You can also use relative paths if you want to navigate between neighbour components.

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Yes that is correct. any path that angular can not find, it should redirect to the 'home' path. That was intended.

Viewing the routes as a tree makes sense, but then even more so I would expect the following:
When I am on the route /home/create-bet and I want to navigate to 'bet-duration-select', I would expect routerLink='./bet-duration-select' to navigate me to said child route of 'create-bet'.

And yet it does not. It redirects me to /home.
And that does not make sense for me...

Also, even if I write the full path as you mentioned, I am still redirected to /home

Comment: @Sven Yes, you're right. And this should work. Check your code, maybe some mistakes there. I created demo with your case and it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pc9mfw?file=src/app/home/home.module.ts

Make sure the button with routerLink placed in right place, or better always use full path and don't worry about paths relations

Comment: Thanks for that stackblitz. It was a missunderstanding on my part regarding the child routes.
Your example and some reading that I did cleared that up for me. Thanks again